# Quickblox update record

Tags: android, quickblox, quickblox-android

I'm new to quickblox. Can anyone tell me how to update a record in custom object?

For example I want to change the `low` value in `water` field to `high`
I just tried the code in quickblox website but it gives me error

I tried

```
String id = getIntent().getStringExtra(Consts.CUSTOMOBJ_ID);

QBCustomObject record = new QBCustomObject();
HashMap<String, Object> fields = new HashMap<String, Object>();
fields.put("mhs",mahasiswa_name.getText().toString());
record.setFields(fields);
record.setCustomObjectId(id);

QBCustomObjects.updateObject(record,null,new QBEntityCallback<QBCustomObject>(){

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(QBCustomObject qbCustomObject, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(QBResponseException e) {

    }
});
```

but it gives me error after `QBCustomObjects.updateObject`:

> ```
>  Cannot resolve method 'updateObject(com.quickblox.customobjects.model.QBCustomObject, null, anonymous
>  com.quickblox.core.QBEntityCallback<com.quickblox.customobjects.model.QBCustomObject>)'
> ```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. Also please make sure to post an error that you are facing otherwise we can't answer the question. Thank you.

Comment: sorry about that i already edit my question

Answer (score 0):

Use the next method:

```
            QBCustomObjects.updateObject(qbCustomObject, qbRequestUpdateBuilder).performAsync(new QBEntityCallback<QBCustomObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QBCustomObject result, Bundle params) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(QBResponseException responseException) {

            }
        });
```